# Preimage/image of surjective morphism between smooth projective varieties of same dimension preserves codimension and rational equivalence relation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective varieties of the same dimension. If $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective. I have two questions, is it true that if we have $U \subset Y$ subvariety of codimension m, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is a subvariety of codimension m?

If $U$ is rationally equivalent to zero on $Y$ does it follow that $f^{-1}(U)$ is rationally equivalent to zero, or any of the adequate relations?

What about its image? Do we know if $K \subset X$ is codimension $r$ in $X$ does it imply that its image $f(K)$ is codimension $r$ in $Y$? What about if $U$ is rationally equivalent to zero is it true it's image is rationally equivalent to zero?

Answer (score 1):

Neither the image, nor the preimage need to have the same codimension. Suppose $Y = \mathbb P^2$ and $f: X \to Y$ is the blow-up of $Y$ in a point $P$. Then $f$ is surjective and both $Y$ and $X$ are $2$-dimensional. The fiber $E = f^{-1}(P)$ is a $\mathbb P^1$, so it has codimension $1$, but $P$ has codimension $2$. For the same reason the codimension of $f(E)$ is bigger than the codimension of $E$.

Since you are asking about rationally equivalent to zero: In general, one can define the pull-back $f^*D$ of a Weil divisor $D$, if $f: X \to Y$ is flat (the example above is not flat), and the push-forward $f_* D$ if $f$ is proper (note: if the dimension of $D$ drops as above, then $f_*D = 0$ by definition). Both operations preserve begin rationally equivalent to zero. For the correct definitions of $f^*$ and $f_*$ and more information I refer to the first chapter of the book *Intersection Theory* by W. Fulton.